# Error with image segmentation with a u-net like architecture mask does not work

Tags: python, keras, jupyter-notebook, image-segmentation

I've tried to compile the code from this website

https://keras.io/examples/vision/oxford_pets_image_segmentation/
the model does work and i obtain good results but the last part (to actually see the image created) does not work on jupyter notebook (it says that the kernel is overrated) and i don't know why, i tried it on multiple computers but the result is always the same

I kept the same code i just changed num_classes for 256 and I reshaped the input images in 256x25

Here is part that does not work :

```
// Generate predictions for all images in the validation set

val_gen = OxfordPets(batch_size, img_size, val_input_img_paths, val_target_img_paths)
val_preds = model.predict(val_gen)


def display_mask(i):
    """Quick utility to display a model's prediction."""
    mask = np.argmax(val_preds[i], axis=-1)
    mask = np.expand_dims(mask, axis=-1)
    img = PIL.ImageOps.autocontrast(keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(mask))
    display(img)


// Display results for validation image #10
i = 10

// Display input image
display(Image(filename=val_input_img_paths[i]))

// Display ground-truth target mask
img = PIL.ImageOps.autocontrast(load_img(val_target_img_paths[i]))
display(img)

// Display mask predicted by our model
display_mask(i)  // Note that the model only sees inputs at 150x150.
```

I would enjoy any help and thank you in advanced for your time.

Comment: I could not find what Kernel is overrated error is in Jupyter notebook. Can you confirm what is the actual error? And provide the full error traceback (as text) that you are getting when you run the last part?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @DivyeshPeshavaria there is no error, jupyter just stops working so i don't know where to start as for what is wrong